# Get element length in loop and get attribute

Tags: javascript, dom

```js
var elements = document.querySelector('.card-blog__footer time');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  let t = elements[i].getAttribute('datetime');
  elements[i].innerHTML(t)
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
<div class="card-blog__footer">
  <time datetime="13:00">12:00</time>
</div>

<div class="card-blog__footer">
  <time datetime="15:00">14:00</time>
</div>
</div>
```

1. `for` not working because `elements.length` always return `undefined`
2. `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined",`
3. `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined",`

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll` - (returns array of elements)  instead of `document.querySelector` (returns only first instance of matching element)

Comment: **Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future** (though there may be a duplicate I should have picked).

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. On SO, you **don't** update the question to incorporate answers. It makes the answers look like nonsense.

Comment: Side note: [`innerHTML` isn't a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, I just want to test the answer on my snippet

Comment: What did *you* try to rectify your issues before dumping them on StackOverflow?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty honestly just google

Comment: So you didn't do any debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

The result returned by the first doesn't have a `length` property

> ... returns the first Element within the document that matches the
>   specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found,
>   null is returned.

while the second has a `length` property

> ... returns a static (not live) [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) representing a list of
>   the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

Also, `innerHTML` is not a function. You need to use it like this:

`elements[i].innerHTML = t;`

Snippet:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.card-blog__footer time');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  let t = elements[i].getAttribute('datetime');
  elements[i].innerHTML = t;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
<div class="card-blog__footer">
  <time datetime="13:00">12:00</time>
</div>

<div class="card-blog__footer">
  <time datetime="15:00">14:00</time>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The length is undefined because `document.querySelector` only returns the first match.

Use `document.querySelectorAll` to get an array-like result.